# Module MSSQL not found on Raspberry PI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymssql

I'm trying to configure MSSQL connector but I got an error that the module is not found. Even the module is installed and exist. Raspberry pi OS.

```
#: python3 --version
Python 3.9.2

#: pip show pymssql
Name: pymssql
Version: 2.2.5
Summary: DB-API interface to Microsoft SQL Server for Python. (new Cython-based version)
Home-page:
Author: Damien Churchill
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages

#: python3 readp.py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymssql._pymmsql'
```

What could be the problem?

readp.py:

```
import pymssql

cnn = pymssql.connect(Server:SERVER;user=USER;password=PWD;database=DB)

empId = 123
print(empId)
cursor = cnn.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE empId = 123"
cursor.execute(query, rd)
firstrow.cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: install the binaries for ubuntu also, you have only downloaded the python package which will alone not work

Comment: Binaries for ubuntu, I'm not sure what could be that, do you have a link?

Comment: i mean try this command sudo apt -y install python3-pymssql

Comment: What does `readp.py` contain? The error complains about `_pymmsql` not `pymssql`

Comment: Searching for `_pymmsql` in the [pymssql Github repo](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql) returns no hits. Is there a typo in `readp.py` perhaps? `pymmsql` alone does appear, as a typo in some questions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is simple python script to connect to DB and execute select query.